# ioinc4 make modal page fit contents height

Tags: ionic-framework

I make modal page that like a alert.
I want modal page height set dynamically
but modal height fixed and made to scroll.

this is my code.

global.scss

```
.custom-modal-alert .modal-wrapper{
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 178px;
    --max-height:1000px;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

What can I do for this problem....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by swapping out the `<ion-content>` tag in your modal page.

```html
 <div class="modal-container">
     <!-- modal contents go here -->
 </div>
```

then add this style to your **global** sass file:

```css
 .custom-modal-alert .modal-wrapper .ion-page {
   position: relative;
   display: contents;
 }
```

NB. This won't work with an `ion-content` tag in your page component. The rest of the styles you have should work